# Does Bluetooth Multipoint allow for playing music on an iPhone and a tutorial YouTube on a PC at the same time?

Tags: mixing, wireless, multichannel

I am having trouble establishing whether Bluetooth Multipoint can stream (and therefor mix) two separate audio streams from say an iPhone and Windows PC for listening to music from the iPhone quietly while also hearing PC sounds like incoming mail alerts or a tutorial video/podcast.

All of the descriptions on the net talk of say playing music on one device and getting a call on another that pauses (so silences) the music to take the call.

Does anyone know about Bluetooth Multipoint, how it works and whether it is able to mix, merge or blend two audio streams from two different sources and play them both though one set of Bluetooth earphones? Like you could with two 3.5mm audio sources and a dedicated two channel mixer output to a set of speakers, amp or headphones.

Thanks,

Gaz